# React: useEffect "paradox" with eventHandler props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Problem with [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts-playground-forked-leq4q?file=/src/index.tsx).

I've got an `Input` component. This input component has an `onChange` prop to handle any data changes from **inside**.

As it should be, if I update the `value` from **outside**, the `onChange` prop is not fired, since nothing changed from inside the input component. If you start typing the `onChange` prop is fired and I can update the state from outside as well.

But if some condition is met (in my example just a boolean state), I want to prefill the input field from inside, therefore I'll have to call an `onChange` event so that the App can update the state from outside.

The problem/paradox is that the `useEffect` checking for a condition now needs the `onChange` prop as a dependency, and since this prop is a method, it will change on every render. This means now the input element always resets to the value from the useEffect when anything is changed because the useEffect is triggered again.

My problem would not be there if I was allowed to remove the `onChange` prop from the useEffect dependency, but this is of course against the rules of the useEffect hook.

The only "solutions" that came to my mind:

- I could move the condition outside of the Input element into the App component. This makes sense for my example, but in the actual scenario the should be the same every time the component is used, and I don't want to repeat the condition every time from outside since the condition is also not just a boolean in the real scenario of course.
- I could add an additional state, whether the condition has already be checked and fire the useEffect only if it has not been triggered yet. But this get really complicated really fast, if the condition needs to get checked again at some point, etc. etc.

I've come across this problem in different shapes scenarios, so I really hope to get an answer that can be applied to similar scenarios in general. Maybe I just have an anti-pattern in my code of how I work with event handlers?

Thank you in advance for all answers ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the if statement to only run if `prefillCondition` has changed. That means you'll need to know what the value was on the last render. Doing that inline would look like:

```
const [prefillCondition, setPrefillCondition] = React.useState(false);
const previous = useRef();
React.useEffect(() => {
  previous.current = prefillCondition;
})
React.useEffect(() => {
  // On the first render, previous.current will be undefined. On every render after that
  // it will tell you what value prefillCondition had on the previous render.
  if (prefillCondition && !previous.current) {
    onChange("value from useEeffff");
  }
}, [onChange, prefillCondition, previous]);
```

I find it common to want to remember a value from the previous render. If you do too, you may want to consider extracting that logic to a custom hook:

```
const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const previous = useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    previous.current = value;
  })
  return previous.current;
}

// used like:
const [prefillCondition, setPrefillCondition] = React.useState(false);
const prevPrefillCondition = usePrevious(prefillCondition);
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (prefillCondition && !prevPrefillCondition) {
    onChange("value from useEeffff");
  }
}, [onChange, prefillCondition, prevPrefillCondition]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this

```
const a = () => 'foo bar'
const b = () => 'foo bar'

a == b // false
```

Even though the function has the same code it has a different memory reference so to React it always appears as a new (changed) prop, that's why it calls re-render
and since you always pass new anonymous onChange callback it calls useEffect each time.

So you could either omit it from the dependencies array (note the ESlint rule)

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    // this would supposibly fetch some default value based on conditions and the call an onChange
    if (prefillCondition) {
      onChange("value from useEeffff");
    }
  }, [prefillCondition]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

or use [`React.useCallback()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) function which solves exactly your problem and prevents creating a new function on every render.

```
const App = () => {
  const [myVal, setMyVal] = React.useState("");

  const handler = React.useCallback((a) => {
    console.log("onchange", a);
    setMyVal(a);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Input value={myVal} onChange={handler} />
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setMyVal("smth");
          }}
        >
          set to smth from outside
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: this solution works and I have thought of it too, it's just not really a good pattern that an event handler needs to be wrapped in a useCallback from the outside every time you use the component.
But for a lot of cases this is enough and this is actually the warning what the React linting already gives you ^^

Answer (score 0):

cant you just have a default value set on the input

`defaultValue={prefillCondition ? "text here" : ""}`

Comment: "default" might be the wrong terminology. The goal is that based on what you click around in the application there is a chance that a condition is met and the input value updates from inside. See my example, the condition is only met once you press the button